# Why c++ iterators of vector before erase position are also invalidated in visual studio?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, invalidation

```
int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int>::iterator iter = nums.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator test = nums.begin(); //used to test
    while (nums.begin() != nums.end())
    {       
        vector<int>::iterator temp = iter;
        vector<int>::iterator temp2 = ++iter;
        if (temp2 == nums.end()) break;
        if (*temp == *temp2)
        {           
            iter = nums.erase(temp);
            cout << *test << " ";  //test here, error happen

        }
    }
    return nums.size();
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> test = { 1,1,2,2,4,5,6,6 };

    int result = removeDuplicates(test);
}
```

error message: `"vector iterator not dereferencable!"` 
I have seen some articles say "iterators before erase position keep valid, only iterators after erase position become invalid." 
But as I try with above code, I found iterators before erase position also become invalid, I don't know why. Please help!

Comment: What is the contents of the vector? Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us? And also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: if I read it correctly you only ever remove the first element, so there is never "iterators before erase position"

Comment: As for a hint about what's probably is happening, what if `nums[0] == nums[1]`? Then you erase `nums[0]` and also dereference an iterator to (the now removed element) `nums[0]`.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, you are right, I get the cause.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  vector<int>::iterator iter = nums.begin();
>  vector<int>::iterator test = nums.begin();
>
>  vector<int>::iterator temp = iter;
> ```

`temp`, `iter` and `test` point to same element.

> ```
>  iter = nums.erase(temp);
> ```

That element is erased. This invalidates `temp` and `test`. `iter` however is reassigned to the next element.

> ```
> cout << *test << " ";
> ```

The invalidated `test` is inderected. Behaviour is undefined.

This situation is reproduced whenever `*temp == *temp2` is true in the first iteration. In later iterations `iter` and `temp` no longer point to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) 
{
    for (auto iter = nums.begin(); iter != nums.end(); /* DO NOT INCREMENT */)
    {
        if (std::find(iter + 1, nums.end(), *iter) != nums.end())
        {
            iter = nums.erase(iter);
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(nums.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) says the following about `vector::erase`:

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

So in your example both `test` and `temp` are initialized with `nums.begin()`. When you  *erase* `temp`, this *invalidates* `temp`. Consequently you need to make sure that `temp` gets re-initialized or you keep a copy of the *erased* element for later usage.

So how about changing you code like this:

```
int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int>::iterator iter = nums.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator test = nums.begin(); //used to test
    while (nums.begin() != nums.end())
    {
        vector<int>::iterator temp = iter;
        vector<int>::iterator temp2 = ++iter;
        size_t dist = std::distance(nums.begin(), temp);
        if (temp2 == nums.end()) break;
        if (*temp == *temp2)
        {
            iter = nums.erase(temp);
            test = nums.begin();
            test += dist;
            cout << *test << " ";  //test here, error happen

        }
    }
    return nums.size();
}
```